# Consume queue from other thread

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I am developing an script in which I want to have 2 threads. One of them will keep reading serial port and the other one will listen to zmq.

I want to use a queue for the first thread know when to stop reading serial port. so I want the second thread, fill a queue with a character each time it receives a message from zmq.

I already have this:

import serial
      import struct
      import threading
      import sys
      import zmq
      from Queue import Queue

```
  ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 38400)
  port = "5556"

  q = Queue(maxsize=0)
  #q = []

  context = zmq.Context()
  socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
  socket.connect("tcp://localhost:%s"% port)
  socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE,'')

  class ReadingThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
      super(ReadingThread, self).__init__()
    def run(self):
      while True:
        if q.empty() == False:
            for element in q:
              print element
        data= ser.read()          print "INT", data

  class ZMQThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
      super(ZMQThread, self).__init__()
    def run(self):
      while True:
        msg = socket.recv()
        #print "RECIBIDO"
        q.put(msg)

  thread1 = ReadingThread()
  thread1.start()
  thread2 = ZMQThread()
  thread2.start()
```

But each time the first thread reach the line with q.empty() it crashes:

```
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
```

I also tested with a for element in q: ... but same result.

How can I consume the queue from the first thread?

Answer (score 1):

`TypeError` caused from `for element in q:` not `q.empty()`. Because `Queue` class doesn't provide `__iter__()` nor `__getitem__()` methods for for-statement.

You should use `get()` method to retrieve the element.